# Refreshing partial view from another partial view, asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to refresh a partial view which defined in main view from another partial view. Is that possible.

```
----MainView.cshtml
{
<div id=1>
   @Html.Partial("partial1", Model)
</div>
<div id=2>
   @Html.Partial("partial2", Model)
</div>
}


---Partial1.cshtml
{
when i click a button, i want to refreh div#2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to refresh the div2 on click.

1) You can bind the click event and perform some action.

e.g. $("#button1").click(function(){

/// Code to refresh div 2

}
)

2) You can raise an event and to the work in registered event.

Comment: Thanks for your helps but how can i call the above AJAX command in JavaScript?